# How to convert my app to an Android TV app?

Tags: android-manifest, android-tv

I have a simple Android application with 2 views (screens).
I'm trying to make my app working on Android TV as well. I don't know what am I doing wrong, but when I run my app on an emulator I don't see my app's logo.

What is wrong in my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx.flagmaster">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/flagmasterlogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:banner="@drawable/flagmastertv"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">    
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    
        <activity android:name=".FlagShowActivity"  
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <intent-filter>    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking your manifest, your icon (location and size) and your app gradle file. I tried creating a project with a basic activity(android) then added:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.4.0'
```

For android TV support and updated my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package_name.tvapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- TV app need to declare touchscreen not required -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <!--
     true:  your app runs on only TV
     false: your app runs on phone and TV
    -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the sample screenshot of the TV emulator. NOTE: I do not own the icon image, it is for testing purposes only.

[image]

Here is the project tree for reference:

[image]

For references:

- [Android TV and Google Cast Development](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-tv-and-google-cast-development--ud875B)
- [Get Started with TV Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html)